# Can I use NUnit TestCase to test mocked repository and real repository

Tags: nunit

I would like to be able to run tests on my fake repository (that uses a list) 
and my real repository (that uses a database) to make sure that both my mocked up version works as expected and my  actual production repository works as expected.   I thought the easiest way would be to use TestCase

```
    private readonly StandardKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel();
    private readonly IPersonRepository fakePersonRepository;
    private readonly IPersonRepository realPersonRepository;
    [Inject]
    public PersonRepositoryTests()
    {

        realPersonRepository = _kernel.Get<IPersonRepository>();
        _kernel = new StandardKernel(new TestModule());
        fakePersonRepository = _kernel.Get<IPersonRepository>();
    }



    [TestCase(fakePersonRepository)]
    [TestCase(realPersonRepository)]
    public void CheckRepositoryIsEmptyOnStart(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        if (personRepository == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Person Repostory never Injected : is Null");
        }
        var records = personRepository.GetAllPeople();

        Assert.AreEqual(0, records.Count());
    }
```

but it asks for a constant expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are a compile-time decoration for an attribute, so anything that you put in a TestCase attribute has to be a constant that the compiler can resolve.

You can try something like this (untested):

```
[TestCase(typeof(FakePersonRespository))]
[TestCase(typeof(PersonRespository))]
public void CheckRepositoryIsEmptyOnStart(Type personRepoType)
{
    // do some reflection based Activator.CreateInstance() stuff here
    // to instantiate the incoming type
}
```

However, this gets a bit ugly because I imagine that your two different implementation might have different constructor arguments. Plus, you really don't want all that dynamic type instantiation code cluttering the test.

A possible solution might be something like this:

```
[TestCase("FakePersonRepository")]
[TestCase("TestPersonRepository")]
public void CheckRepositoryIsEmptyOnStart(string repoType)
{
    // Write a helper class that accepts a string and returns a properly 
    // instantiated repo instance. 
    var repo = PersonRepoTestFactory.Create(repoType);

    // your test here
}
```

Bottom line is, the test case attribute has to take a constant expression. But you can achieve the desired result by shoving the instantiation code into a factory.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute, though that may fail with the same error.  Otherwise, you may have to settle for two separate tests, which both call a third method to handle all of the common test logic.